# How to restrict backtracking in a monad transformer parser combinator

Tags: parsing, haskell, monad-transformers, parser-combinators, monadplus

**tl;dr,** How do I implement parsers whose backtracking can be restricted, where the parsers are monad transformer stacks?

I haven't found any papers, blogs, or example implementations of this approach;  it seems the typical approach to restricting backtracking is a datatype with additional constructors, or the Parsec approach where backtracking is off by default.

My current implementation -- using a `commit` combinator, see below -- is wrong; I'm not sure about the types, whether it belongs in a type class, and my instances are less generic than it feels like they should be.

Can anyone describe how to do this cleanly, or point me to resources?

I've added my current code below; sorry for the post being so long!

---

The stack:

```
StateT
MaybeT/ListT
Either e
```

The intent is that backtracking operates in the middle layer -- a `Nothing` or an empty list wouldn't necessarily yield an error, it'd just mean that a different branch should be tried --  whereas the bottom layer is for errors (with some contextual information) that immediately abort the parsing.

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction, FunctionalDependencies, 
             FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}

import Control.Monad.Trans.State   (StateT(..))
import Control.Monad.State.Class   (MonadState(..))
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe   (MaybeT(..))
import Control.Monad.Trans.List    (ListT(..))
import Control.Monad               (MonadPlus(..), guard)    

type Parser e t mm a = StateT [t] (mm (Either e)) a

newtype DParser e t a = 
    DParser {getDParser :: Parser e t MaybeT a}

instance Monad (DParser e t) where
  return = DParser . return
  (DParser d) >>= f = DParser (d >>= (getDParser . f))

instance MonadPlus (DParser e t) where
  mzero = DParser (StateT (const (MaybeT (Right Nothing))))
  mplus = undefined   -- will worry about later

instance MonadState [t] (DParser e t) where
  get = DParser get
  put = DParser . put
```

A couple of parsing classes:

```
class (Monad m) => MonadParser t m n | m -> t, m -> n where
  item  :: m t
  parse :: m a -> [t] -> n (a, [t])

class (Monad m, MonadParser t m n) => CommitParser t m n where
  commit :: m a -> m a
```

Their instances:

```
instance MonadParser t (DParser e t) (MaybeT (Either e)) where
  item = 
      get >>= \xs -> case xs of
                          (y:ys) -> put ys >> return y;
                          []     -> mzero;
  parse = runStateT . getDParser

instance CommitParser t (DParser [t] t) (MaybeT (Either [t])) where
  commit p =
      DParser (
        StateT (\ts -> MaybeT $ case runMaybeT (parse p ts) of
                            Left e          ->  Left e;
                            Right Nothing   ->  Left ts;
                            Right (Just x)  ->  Right (Just x);))
```

And a couple more combinators:

```
satisfy f = 
    item >>= \x ->
    guard (f x) >>
    return x

literal x = satisfy (== x)
```

Then these parsers:

```
ab = literal 'a' >> literal 'b'

ab' = literal 'a' >> commit (literal 'b')
```

give these results:

```
> myParse ab "abcd"
Right (Just ('b',"cd"))  -- succeeds

> myParse ab' "abcd"
Right (Just ('b',"cd"))  -- 'commit' doesn't affect success

> myParse ab "acd"
Right Nothing       -- <== failure but not an error

> myParse ab' "acd"
Left "cd"           -- <== error b/c of 'commit'
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but are the results you give the results that you want or that you currently get. (If the latter, what result do you want?)

Comment: @dbaupp both -- the code 'works' right now but only for that specific monad stack.  My goal is to figure out the 'right' way to do this, or at least a better/cleaner/general way.

Answer (score 2):

The answer appears to be in the [`MonadOr` type class](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/MonadPlus_reform_proposal) (which unfortunately for me is not part of the standard libraries):

> ```
> class MonadZero m => MonadOr m where   
>   morelse :: m a -> m a -> m a
> ```
>
> satisfying Monoid and Left Catch:
>
> ```
> morelse mzero b = b 
> morelse a mzero = a 
> morelse (morelse a b) c = morelse a (morelse b c) 
> morelse (return a) b = return a
> ```